# How to highlight a string within a string ignoring whitespace and non alphanumeric chars?

Tags: regex, search, replace, whitespace, match

What is the best way to produce a highlighted string found within another string?

I want to ignore all character that are not alphanumeric but retain them in the final output.

So for example a search for 'PC3000' in the following 3 strings would give the following results:

```
   ZxPc 3000L = Zx<font color='red'>Pc 3000</font>L

   ZXP-C300-0Y  =  ZX<font color='red'>P-C300-0</font>Y

   Pc3 000  =   <font color='red'>Pc3 000</font>
```

I have the following code but the only way i can highlight the search within the result is to remove all the whitespace and non alphanumeric characters and then set both strings to lowercase. I'm stuck!

```
public string Highlight(string Search_Str, string InputTxt)
    {

        // Setup the regular expression and add the Or operator.
        Regex RegExp = new Regex(Search_Str.Replace(" ", "|").Trim(), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        // Highlight keywords by calling the delegate each time a keyword is found.
        string Lightup = RegExp.Replace(InputTxt, new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceKeyWords));

        if (Lightup == InputTxt)
        {
            Regex RegExp2 = new Regex(Search_Str.Replace(" ", "|").Trim(), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            RegExp2.Replace(" ", "");

            Lightup = RegExp2.Replace(InputTxt.Replace(" ", ""), new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceKeyWords));

            int Found = Lightup.IndexOf("<font color='red'>");

            if (Found == -1)
            {
                Lightup = InputTxt;
            }

        }

        RegExp = null;
        return Lightup;
    }

    public string ReplaceKeyWords(Match m)
    {
        return "<font color='red'>" + m.Value + "</font>";
    }
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: Could you please provide an example of input and output? I assume the base is "strip html tags and then find the string even if there are spaces in it", am I right? also, with 'highlighted' you mean colored in red?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alter your search string by inserting an optional non-alphanumeric character class (`[^a-z0-9]?`) between each character. Instead of `PC3000` use

```
P[^a-z0-9]?C[^a-z0-9]?3[^a-z0-9]?0[^a-z0-9]?0[^a-z0-9]?0
```

This matches `Pc 3000`, `P-C300-0` and `Pc3 000`.

Comment: I'm not sure where to do this. So I change the string to:    string X = "";

            foreach (char c in InputTxt)
            {
                X += c.ToString() + "[^a-z0-9]?";
            }

            InputTxt = X;

Comment: You have to alter `Search_Str`, not `InputTxt`

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to create a version of the input string that only contains alphanumerics and a lookup array that maps character positions from the new string to the original input. Then search the alphanumeric-only version for the keyword(s) and use the lookup to map the match positions back to the original input string.

Pseudo-code for building the lookup array:

```
cleanInput = "";
lookup = [];
lookupIndex = 0;

for ( index = 0; index < input.length; index++ ) {
    if ( isAlphaNumeric(input[index]) {
        cleanInput += input[index]; 
        lookup[lookupIndex] = index;
        lookupIndex++;
    }
}
```